# Unable to find localedef command on centos6

Tags: centos, localization

I am on CentOS 6.5 and I am unable to find localedef.
I searched on /usr/bin but Ican't find it
I don't also know if it comes in a package, i have searched on google and found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On CentOS you can use rpm -qf to find which package contains a file if you know it's full path

```
rpm -qf /usr/bin/localedef
```

If you don't know it's full path yu can do a search using yum

```
yum provides '*/localedef'
```

You'll find that it's in package glibc-common.

Comment: I had glibc-common installed but I hadn't localedef, after a reinstall it's fine now, thanks